# attaching a custom query to WP_Query, wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following query

```
select 
    tab1.post_id,
    ((tab1.meta_value - tab2.meta_value) / tab1.meta_value) * 100 as discount
from
    fridaysunday.wp_postmeta as tab1,
    fridaysunday.wp_postmeta as tab2
where
    tab1.post_id = tab2.post_id and tab1.meta_key = 'price' and tab2.meta_key = 'sale_price'
order by discount desc;
```

I want to integrate this query with the WP_Query function.
Greatly appreciate your help, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

$query = 'select 
    '.$prefix.'tab1.post_id,
    (('.$prefix.'tab1.meta_value - '.$prefix.'tab2.meta_value) / '.$prefix.'tab1.meta_value) * 100 as discount
from
    '.$prefix.'wp_postmeta as tab1,
    '.$prefix.'wp_postmeta as tab2
where
    '.$prefix.'tab1.post_id = '.$prefix.'tab2.post_id and '.$prefix.'tab1.meta_key = 'price' and '.$prefix.'tab2.meta_key = 'sale_price'
order by discount desc";

$records = $wpdb->get_results($query);



?>
```

Comment: how are you integrating this query with WP_Query() ?